# Question about uniform convergence interval

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I want to determine in what interval this series has uniform convergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^n $$

Finding the radius of convergence is easy, since $|1-x|<1$

$$-1<1-x<1 $$
$$0<x<2 $$

The convergence radius is therefore $\rho=1$. To determine the range of uniform convergence, I use this proposition from my text book.

> **Proposition 5.30** Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $\rho>0$.  Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$ is uniformly convergent on any interval of the form $[-r,r]$, where $r\in]0,\rho[$.

It tells me to choose an $r$ from the interval, $]0,1[$. Then the series is convergent in $[-r,r]$, but I don't see how this can be true.

Say I choose $r=0.5$, then the series is unformly convergent in $[-0.5,0.5]$.

But now the series doesn't even converge, since $|1+0.5|>1$, and it becomes divergent.

---

### Origin of this question

This question was originally a multiple choice question, asking in what interval $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^n $ is uniformly convergent. There were, among others, these two choices

1. $\frac{1}{4} \leq  x \leq \frac{3}{4}$
2. $0<x<1$

It turns out that the correct answer is $\frac{1}{4} \leq  x \leq \frac{3}{4}$, but I don't see why the second choice isn't correct. We know that $x$ can come arbitrarily close to $0$, and still ensure uniform convergence. We have also seen (from comments on John's answer) that $0.1 \leq \leq 1.9 x$ ensures uniform convergence. So why can't we say that $0<x<1$ ensures uniform convergence?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^n$ is a power series about $1$ while $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n$ is a power series about $0$.  They are not the same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series does not have the form indicated in the theorem -- the theorem involves powers of a single variable; your series involves powers of $(1-x)$.

If you let $y = 1-x$, then you can apply the theorem to the series
$$
\sum y^n
$$
to conclude an interval of uniform convergence in $y$; you can then use this to say for which $x$ the original series converges uniformly.

Comment: One more question: Say I choose $r=0.9$, so $y \in [-0.9, 0.9] $ and so uniform convergence for $ 0.1 \leq x \leq 1.9$. For uniform convergence $x$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ by choosing a larger $r$. We also just Saw that when $0.1<x \leq 1$ we have uniform convergence. Can we then, for example, also say that we have uniform convergence for $0<x<1$? @JohnHughes

Comment: You seem to be asking "If I know something is true for every interval of the form $1-a < x < 1 + a$, where $0 \le a < 1$, do I also know it's true for the case $a = 1$? The answer is, in general, "no". For instance, the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x(2-x)}$ is bounded on all such intervals for $0 \le a < 1$, but when you try to extend to $a = 1$, the function isn't even defined!

Comment: Thanks for the answer again, John. But I still have a question. I edited my original question - sorry for creating an "XY"-problem. @JohnHughes

Comment: I suspect that the exact phrasing of the multiple choice question was something like "in which of the following intervals is [this] uniformly convergent." If a series is uniformly convergent on  $[3, 5]$, it's also uniformly convergent on $[3.4, 4.1]$, or any other subinterval of $[3, 5]$, and **may** be uniformly convergent on the whole real line. If you say "my shirt's cuffs are blue", that entails the claim "my shirt's left cuff is blue", and does not preclude the collar or the whole shirt being blue. My guess is that exactly one of the options listed was on for which the claim was valid.